# ¿Como puedo obtener el dato de la primera columna de una fila de una tabla en html dando click al boton dentro del td con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```js
$("table > tbody > tr > td > button").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Click")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead id="Thead-rol">
<tr><th class="none">Dato1</th><th>Rol</th><th>Estatus</th><th>Editar</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="Tbody-rol">
<tr><td class="none">Dato 1</td><td>Dato 2</td><td><button class="btn bg-success">Activo</button></td><th><button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></th> </tr></tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Lo que busco es dar clic en el botón de la columna Estatus, el cual es un botón y obtener el dato 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy llenando una tabla dinámica con la función `.append()` de `JQuery` (Se me facilita más para manipular el `DOM` como `DOMString`) por lo que tuve problemas para que me funcionara el `Event Click` de las respuestas anteriores, por lo que mi solución fue la siguiente:

Dado que estoy manipulando el `DOM`tuve que recurrir al siguiente evento, ya que la documentación que encontré dice que no tendría problemas al momento de actualizar mi `DOM`

```
$(selector).on(event,childSelector,function);
```

**Solución:**

```
 $("#Tbody").on("click", "tr > td > button", function() {

     var temp = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();

      alert("Valor: "+temp);

  }
```

**`.closest()`:** busca el elemento mas cercano del selector que se le indica

**`.find()`:** Recorre todos los descendientes hacia abajo del selector indicado

**`.eq()`:** Se indica la posición del elemento a obtener

Answer (score 1):

No veo la necesidad de un selector tan largo considerando que:

- Las celdas pueden tener clases que las identifiquen por grupos
- O puedes aplicar un par de clases, una para el botón y otra para el Dato1
- No requieres de JQuery para conseguir el resultado
- Obtén a cada elemento como mencionamos por su clase y asignalos a variables
- Al botón le das un listener en su evento click
- Posterior cuando ese evento sea disparado, entonces mandas a *imprimir* la propiedad `innerText` de la celda que tiene el dato1

Propuesta:

```html
    <table>
      <thead id="Thead-rol">
        <tr>
          <th class="none">Dato1</th>
          <th>Rol</th>
          <th>Estatus</th>
          <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="Tbody-rol">
        <tr>
          <td class="none">Dato 1</td>
          <td>Dato 2</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn bg-success take-value">Activo</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>Otro </button>
          </td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    
    <script>
      let takeValue = document.querySelector('.take-value');
      let valorUno  = document.querySelector('.none');
      
      
      takeValue.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(valorUno.innerText);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Creo que me falto explicar en el problema que la tabla será dinámica, y es por eso que buscaba que el selector obtuviera los datos de la fila.

Comment: osea que quieres que ese click funcione por cada botón y te ayude a obtener el valor de cada celda ?

Comment: @FernyCortez osea que quieres este mismo comportamiento pero por cada botón que tenga la tabla no?

Answer (score 1):

para navegar a través de tu tabla utilizando JQuery necesitas asignar en este caso un id a tu tabla y ocupar la siguiente línea:

```
var temp = $('#tabla tbody tr').children(':first').html();
```

Esta buscará siempre el primer elemento de tu tabla. Tu código quedaría así:

```js
$("table > tbody > tr > td > button").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var temp = $('#tabla tbody tr').children(':first').html();
    alert("Clickeaste: " + temp);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tabla'>
<thead id="Thead-rol">
<tr><th class="none">Dato1</th><th>Rol</th><th>Estatus</th><th>Editar</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="Tbody-rol">
<tr><td class="none">Dato 1</td><td>Dato 2</td><td><button class="btn bg-success">Activo</button></td><th><button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></th> </tr></tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se dispara el evento click, se pasa como argumento un objeto, que tiene como propiedad `.target` al elemento que lo disparó (el botón en el que hiciste click). En tu código:

```
e.target
```

Primero estás buscando seleccionar el primer `tr` padre de este botón. Con `.closest()` lo obtenemos:

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').
```

Y luego el texto del primer `td`:

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()
```

```js
$("table > tbody > tr > td > button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let primeraColumna = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  console.log(primeraColumna)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="Thead-rol">
    <tr>
      <th class="none">Dato1</th>
      <th>Rol</th>
      <th>Estatus</th>
      <th>Editar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Tbody-rol">
    <tr>
      <td class="none">Dato 1</td>
      <td>Dato 2</td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-success">Activo</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="none">Dato 3</td>
      <td>Dato 4</td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-success">Activo</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="none">Dato 5</td>
      <td>Dato 6</td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-success">Activo</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn bg-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```